# PHP redirected page doesn't have a referral url

Tags: php, http, redirect, google-analytics

I have two site `sitea.com` and `siteb.com`

I need to redirect pages from `sitea.com` to `siteb.com`. The redirect script in `sitea.com` is

```
<?php
header("Location: http://siteb.com/somepage");
?>
```

The redirection is taking without any flaw. The functionality if fulfilled. But I have google analytics tracking on siteb.com which should show that the source is referral from sitea.com

I dug into web developer tools in google chrome and found that `siteb.com` doesn't send a referral header in the request.

**How do i redirect my visitors from `sitea.com` to `siteb.com` which sends the referral headers on `siteb.com`.?**

Comment: I would encourage you to redirect with the web server rather than the code.

Comment: There are some work that will happen in database so i can't use webserver to redirect. Some scripts are to be executed before redirection.

Comment: I don't think you can,  `Referrer` is a header sent by the browser in the request.  EDIT: I found a suggestion [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?576633-How-to-get-the-PHP-header()-function-to-actually-send-a-referrer): `It you go directly to the redirect page, it doesn't send a referrer, you have to click on a link to go to the redirection page.`

Comment: You cannot force the client to do anything. Relying on the `Referer:` header for anything at all is a flawed design. Expecting the designers of HTTP to spell the word "referrer" correctly is also a flawed approach which cannot be relied upon (pet peeve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The best way to keep the referal is to issue a standard 301 from the server.**

How to do this using **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Doing it straight from PHP should also work (as pointed out by [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom)) just be sure to include the HTTP response code.

```
<?php
// 301 Moved Permanently
header("Location: http://siteb.com/somepage", TRUE, 301);
```

And bellow a table with data from diferent ways to re-direct and it's impact on analytics.

```
Redirect method             | Browser   | Result            | Impact on analytics
----------------------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------
Meta refresh - 0            | Firefox 3 | Blank referrer    | Lost data
                            | IE8       | Blank referrer    | Lost data
                            | Opera 9   | Internal referrer | Lost data
Javascript:location.href    | Firefox 3 | Internal referrer | Lost data
                            | IE8       | Blank referrer    | Lost data
                            | Opera 9   | Internal referrer | Lost data
Javascript:location.replace | Firefox 3 | Internal referrer | Lost data
                            | IE8       | Blank referrer    | Lost data
                            | Opera 9   | Internal referrer | Lost data
Server-side 301             | Firefox 3 | Original referrer | 
                            | IE8       | Original referrer | 
                            | Opera 9   | Original referrer | 
Server-side 302             | Firefox 3 | Original referrer | 
                            | IE8       | Original referrer | 
                            | Opera 9   | Original referrer | 
Server-side 301 - chained   | Firefox 3 | Original referrer | 
                            | IE8       | Original referrer | 
                            | Opera 9   | Original referrer | 
Server-side 302 - chained   | Firefox 3 | Original referrer | 
                            | IE8       | Original referrer | 
                            | Opera 9   | Original referrer |
```

[Original link for the above table.](http://www.receptional.com/blog/how-to-redirect-and-keep-referrer-data-for-web-analytics)

Comment: @Rocket thanks for the edit, was working on it but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Frankie: No problem!  The formatting was bugging me, so I had to fix it ^^

Comment: It's worth noting that the OPs original code (just setting a `Location:` header) should result in a server side 302 because of the way PHP handles it. It's also worth noting that depending on the circumstances 303 might be more semantically correct.

Comment: @DaveRandom, you're correct, updated the answer to explicitly point this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the client always setting the header for you, but you can pass a throw-away parameter that you then track with Google Analytics. E.g.:

```
header("Location: http://siteb.com/somepage?source=sitea");
```